# open port on ubuntu in azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure

I have created an ubuntu image in windows azure vm. I am trying to open port 7171 to the outside world. how can I do it?

I have tried issue the iptables command but it did not work, not sure if I did not use it correctly or there is azure level setting to set?

EDIT: maybe it is opened only on localhost and not to the world? how can I verify that?

Comment: can you give us the output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: the output is empty. tried to redirect output with > but still empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add it as an endpoint instead. From the Windows Azure preview portal, select Virtual Machines -> Your virtual machine. Then click the endpoints tab and finally New. You can see there that only SSH port is open by default.

Comment: How can do this in New Portal,

Answer (score 16):

Using Azure's new portal:

1. Open your VM.
2. Go to Network interfaces in the Settings window
3. Click on your network interface
4. In the network interface window, there is a "**Network security group**" section
5. In the network security group's settings click on "**Inbound security rules**"
6. Add a new rule

I'm not sure if there is a shorter way of getting there.. Next time I'll make sure to set up my ports when creating a VM.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer version of the Azure portal (v3) the steps are slightly different now. If you select virtual machines from the left menu and then select a specific VM and then select Networking you can add inbound/outbound rules for specific ports for each VM.

**screenshot #1**

[image: ss #1]

**screenshot #2**

[image: ss #2]

#### References

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/nsg-quickstart